# How to reset the javascript '.one' function after code executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a button that avoids user clicks multiple times at the same time. I tried

Method 1:

```
$(document).one('click','.button',function(){
    //coding......
});
```

Method 2:

```
$(document).on('click','.button',function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    //coding....
    $(this).prop('disabled',false);
});
```

In method 1, is it possible to reset the function '.one'?
Because I allow user to click again if the part of '//coding'
return false.
Or maybe there is another option?

Comment: You'll have to explicitly disable the handler (or the property) if you only want to conditionally disable it.

Comment: what is the problem with second method? `//coding` represent means what is ajax call or simple dom?

Comment: @prasanth the '//coding' contains some error checking and ajax

Comment: For this kind of scenario, I always recommend [debounced](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) function

Comment: @hackape thx, I will try that

Comment: add `$(this).prop('disabled',false);` inside the ajax [ajax.done()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. Its enable button after ajax call fail/error/success

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without getting more specific into the use case. This snippet is just an example of an async action (mocked with setTimeout). This just toggles the disabled property. You can also add/remove event listeners if need be.

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('button')

const onClick = e => {
  button1.disabled = true
  setTimeout(() => {
    const x = Math.round(Math.random())
    if (x) {
      button.disabled = false
    } else {
      const button2 = document.createElement('button')
      button2.textContent = 'Reset'
      button2.onclick = e => {
        button1.disabled = false
        button2.remove()
      }
      document.body.appendChild(button2)
    }
  }, 1000)
}

button1.addEventListener('click', onClick)
```

```html
<button id='button'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the button is disabled or not. If it isn't, then set it to disabled and execute your code.

```
$(document).on('click','.button',function(){
    if ($(this).prop('disabled') === false) {
      $(this).prop('disabled',true);
         //put your code here
    }
});
```